# Error when Access to database on Windows phone

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone

When I click a button on my app...it show the error on this code: **member = (from emp in context.Members select emp).ToList();**

Please help me to solve it

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.Phone.Data.Internal.ni.dll but was not handled in user
>   code

```
{System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database. [ Data Source = C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData\{B4AFF75E-E308-4B3B-B77C-7E66E36E2513}\Local\Name.sdf ]
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult, Boolean isCompiledQuery)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Boolean isCompiledQuery)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Member.DBHelper.GetMember()
   at Member.Show.Viewmember_Loaded()
   at Member.Show..ctor()}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: The database file cannot be found. Check if the file exists and if not, create it.

Comment: i have generated the datacontext from a *.sdf file by using Sqlmetal and add the .cs file into the solution. what do u mean create it?

Comment: The .sdf file has to exist on the device too otherwise the datacontext is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have this somewhere in you app.xaml.vb:

```
Private Sub CreateDatabase()
    Using c As DataContext = New DataContext(DataContext.ConnectionString)
        c.CreateIfNotExists()
        c.LogDebug = True
    End Using
End Sub
```

Then call it from your App.xaml.vb like this:

```
Public Sub New()
    '...other initialisation codes
    Call CreateDatabase()
End Sub
```

You can convert if you want c#